# Change element value on onkeypress event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web, dom-events, onkeydown, onkeypress

Please help me with my script. I don't understand why it does not work:

```html
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input" onkeypress="myFunction()">
<input type="button" value="Hallo" id="but">
<script>
function myFunction{
    document.getElementById('but').value = "changed";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: typo: should be `function myFunction () {`

Comment: thanks) Im frequently doing mistakes like this

Comment: @edgar-p-yan. It's nice to get into the habit of setting break-points or at least do some `console.log("inside function")` so that you can see at which stage the code if failing. The output is shown in the console (in Chrome you can access it by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + I  and switching to the Console tab.  There you can also see any error message, and they may indicate where/what your error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple you have forgotten to place parantheses after myFunction.

your code should be:

```
 <script>
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById('but').value = "changed";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This way it work. Function needs parenthesis

```js
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById('but').value = "changed";
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="input" onkeypress="myFunction()">
    <input type="button" value="Hallo" id="but">

    </body>
    </html>
```

an alternative way is

```
    myFunction = function () {
        document.getElementById('but').value = "changed";
    }
```